# Customize Eclipse RCP perspective toolbar programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am working on an Eclipse RCP application which contains almost all Eclipse features and icons, and with some additional features.
I have created my own perspective using the interface IPerspectiveFactory

```
public class PerspectiveFactory implements IPerspectiveFactory {

@Override
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

the perspective contains the Eclipse Toolbar with eclipse icons also with my additional toobar icons.

My Question is How could I access the eclipse toolbar programmatically for this perspective to remove not needed Eclipse icons, rather than doing it manually from "Customize perspective" menu in the RCP.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point

Comment: thanks, it works and Toolbar icon is Hidden, BUT there is a free space in place of the icon, Also the icon is still checked in the Customize perspective window, Also it can`t be returned it back unhidden.
Is there Another way Just similar to Uncheck the Toolbar icon from Cutomize prespective Window ?